# Firefox this page has no sources

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a JavaScript game and it works as intended in Chrome and Safari. However, in Firefox, the page doesn't load any scripts, and the debugger is empty. I'm not seeing any errors at all. This is the entirety of the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script type="module" src="foo.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="bar.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="baz.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="qux.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="foobar.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="bazqux.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: Some added context for future readers: per Roko C. Buljan's answer, it turns out ES6 modules are not on by default in FireFox at the time of writing. That was the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `module` features not openly available in Firefox. To enable them you could go to `about:config` and enable them under  `dom.moduleScripts.enabled` setting its ***Value*** to `true`

[image]

Meanwhile you could [use a polyfill like this](https://github.com/matthewp/script-type-module) or use [build tools](https://webpack.js.org/) that will compile your modules into a single ES5-backed production-ready file.

Some indepth readings:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#integration-with-the-javascript-module-system
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script
https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/
https://medium.com/webpack/the-state-of-javascript-modules-4636d1774358

Comment: Doesn't the type need to be "module" for me to use the import/export statements?